# Can I call system() from a Windows service

Tags: c++, windows, service, lua

Is it possible to call `system()` to execute a subprocess within the context of a Windows Service?

I've implemented a Windows service in C++ using a boiler plate project: [A basic Windows service](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948)

The service is started with Local System account and desktop interaction permissions and is running various code in a timer-based object including file operations on the disk.

However, things like `system("C:\\bin\\sth.exe some-param");` or running lua code from static libraries don't work within the windows service. I've made sure they work at all by running them in a console application.

Any clues?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what happens when you try?

Comment: (1) Install the windows service, set 'log on as' to 'local system', start it. ("non-service" part of the service-installer executable has no problems running sys calls). (2) Service running in the background, running some disk operations, doing some logging - all good. (3) Sys calls, however, are just not executed and nothing happens.

Comment: Some applications simply won't run in system service context because they depend on functionality that isn't available.  For example, they might depend on a missing environment variable, or require Explorer to be running, or make use of per-user registry settings that are created when a user first logs on.  The simplest way to test whether a given executable has trouble running in a service context is to use `psexec` (downloadable from Microsoft).

Comment: It is also possible that the C libraries `system` command itself has such a dependency.  Try using the native `CreateProcess` instead and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: The phrase "system call" is usually used to refer to calls into the operating system's published API. The C runtime function `system()` is implemented with the system call [`execl(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) or one of its close relatives on Unix, and by likely by `CreateProcess()` or a close relative on Windows. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CreateProcess so you can get error code. If that doesn't help, take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/105447/, it has some important info about Local System limitations and links to workarounds (in particular http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18367/Launch-your-application-in-Vista-under-the-local-s).

Comment: I will look into this. Having a hard time getting any event or error code from this, since the service is just running happily in the background and actually doing most of its work.

Comment: As I see it, I can only achieve what I want with the method CreateProcessAsUser. I "just" have to provide the right Access-Token security handle. Another adventure in Windows Wonderland ahead of me...